# How to hide referrer in safari browser?

Tags: php, safari, http-headers, http-referer, referrer-policy

I am using header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer"); in PHP to hide referrer its working in all browser except safari and edge. How can i achieve the same functionality of hide referrer in safari also. Please help me with the suitable code for this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect behaviour in Safari (referrer being set to the domain only, without the URI), pertains to the fact that Prevent cross-site tracking is enabled. Setting:

```html
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
<meta http-equiv='Referrer-Policy' content='no-referrer-when-downgrade'>
```

or setting

```html
referrerPolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
```

on the element (iframe, script tag, etc) does not affect it.